# html table ignoring the white space characters in python string when rendred with flask jinja template

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I have a python string like this:

```
my_string = 'Variance           -2592.41'
```

I want to display this string as it is on html page rendered using flask **render_template** function. But the same string appears like **'Variance-2592.41'** on the UI (all the white spaces in between are ignored automatically). I am not able to understand why this is happening. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to either wrap it in `pre` tags, or you need to use the `&nbsp;` element, one for each desired empty space.

Background info: in HTML all spaces get folded to a single one.

Also, you could split your string and put the data into separate `<td>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

use Flask.Markup for escaping tags from string.

```
from markupsafe import Markup
```

edit render_tempale methode.

```
return render_template("index.html",message = Markup('Variance &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp -2592.41'));
```

this will solve the problem. Tested.